# Spring security login over ssl on port 8443 not recognized on port 8080 with http protocol

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tomcat8

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour trying to secure my login form.

My app is developed over Spring Framework and Spring Security and deployed on a Tomcat server.
Everything works fine using only http, but when I use https 8443 port for my login page, after a successfull login and a redirect lo http://localhost:8080/mens/index I get redirected to login page at https://localhost:8443/mens/login.html

This is (part of) the configuration of my spring-security.xml:

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.html?invalidSession=1" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="http"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/upload/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http"/>

    <headers>
        <xss-protection block="false"/>
        <frame-options disabled="true"/>
        <cache-control/>
    </headers>

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login.html" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=1" 
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?logout=1" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <!-- <csrf disabled="true" /> -->
</http>
```

Alternatively, I tried to use a channelProcessingFilter instead of the requires-channel attribute:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter position="CHANNEL_FILTER" ref="channelProcessingFilter"/>

    <custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.html?invalidSession=1" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/upload/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <headers>
        <xss-protection block="false"/>
        <frame-options disabled="true"/>
        <cache-control/>
    </headers>

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login.html" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=1" 
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?logout=1" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <!-- <csrf disabled="true" /> -->
</http>

<beans:bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager"/>
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <filter-security-metadata-source request-matcher="regex">
            <intercept-url pattern="\A/login.*\Z" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="\A/login.html.*\Z" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="\A/.*\Z" access="ANY_CHANNEL"/>
        </filter-security-metadata-source>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
    <beans:property name="channelProcessors">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
            <beans:ref bean="insecureChannelProcessor"/>
            <beans:ref bean="anyChannelProcessor"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="com.mycompany.mens.springsecurity.MensSecureChannelProcessor"/>
<beans:bean id="insecureChannelProcessor" class="com.mycompany.mens.springsecurity.MensInsecureChannelProcessor"/>
<beans:bean id="anyChannelProcessor" class="com.mycompany.mens.springsecurity.MensAnyChannelProcessor">
    <beans:property name="entryPoint" ref="mensRetryWithHttpEntryPoint"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean name="mensRetryWithHttpEntryPoint" class="com.mycompany.mens.springsecurity.MensRetryWithHttpEntryPoint"/>
```

Debugging I found that authentication is successfull, entry point redirects the flow to index page on http port 8080, but after that something is redirecting me to login form another time.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much in advance, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login page requires HTTPS:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https"/>
```

but your index page requires HTTP:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http"/>
```

that's the reason, why you lose your session cookie, see [Spring Security - Frequently Answered Questions (FAQ)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session):

> **2.3.
>   I'm using Tomcat (or some other servlet container) and have enabled HTTPS for my login page, switching back to HTTP afterwards. It doesn't work - I just end up back at the login page after authenticating.**
>
> This happens because sessions created under HTTPS, for which the session  cookie is marked as “secure”, cannot subsequently be used under HTTP. The browser will not send the cookie back to the server and any session state will be lost (including the security context information). Starting a session in HTTP first should work as the session cookie won't be marked as secure (you will also have to disable Spring Security's  Session Fixation Protection support to prevent it from creating a new secure session on login (you can always create a new session yourself at a later stage). Note that switching between HTTP and HTTPS is not a good idea in general, as any application which uses HTTP at all is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. To be truly secure, the user should begin accessing your site in HTTPS and continue using it until they log out. Even clicking on an HTTPS link from a page accessed over HTTP is potentially risky. If you need more convincing, check out a tool like sslstrip.

Comment: can you please expalain how you solved the issue @GreyStar

Comment: @nanospeck I changed this:
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http"/>
with
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>

Comment: Thanks. Mine was annotation driven and adding code `http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()` to `WebSecurityConfigurereAdapter`'s child class in my application helped solve the issue.